# React Native, getting "Module not found: Can't resolve" error while using ImageBackground

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Got this error while making background image to modal window :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using an external image, so the way is to give `source` an object with `uri` field instead of using `require`, like so:

```
<ImageBackground 
  source={{uri:'https://via.placeholder.com/500'}}> 
  resizeMode="cover" 
  style={styles.imgBackground}
>
   <Text>Some text...</Text>
</ImageBackground>
```